# Tabs title change based on selected tab

Tags: html

I have a tab with this code

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs pull-right">
    <li><a href="#tab_3-2" target="_self" data-toggle="tab">tab3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab_2-2" target="_self" data-toggle="tab">tab2</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab_1-1" target="_self" data-toggle="tab">tab1</a></li>
    <li class="pull-left header"><i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> title</li>
</ul>
```

As you can see it has one title and I want a different title based on selected tab.
So if I selected tab1 change title to title1, if tab2 change to title2 etc

Can you help me?

Comment: What is "title1","title2" etc..? are they URL's?

Comment: do you have any javascript or jquery for this?

Comment: what i want to change is the last <li> (the title name) if user selects tab 1 ,2 or 3